# какой командой в bash сделать так, чтобы в случайном четырехзначном числе не было повторяющихся цифр?

Tags: bash, shell, случайные-числа

пока есть только это
n=$(shuf -i 1000-9999 -n 1)

Comment: `shuf -i 1234-9876 | grep -vP '(.).*\1' | head -1`

Comment: @AlexeyTen нижняя граница 1023

Comment: Ага, ошибся. =)

Comment: @AlexeyTen, да спасибо, работает, только я не поняла, как работает Ваш шаблон, можете пояснить?

Comment: Это случаем не проблема XY? Зачем могло понадобиться такое число?

Comment: @user7860670 нет, это для игры нужно

Comment: Игра на bash? О_о Или ты водишь DnD и замахало кидать кубик?

Comment: @Надя https://regex101.com/r/3dZwLR/1 под регулярное выражение подходят строки с повторяющимися цифрами, а флаг `-v` инвертирует выбор, т.е. `grep` наоборот выбирает строки не подходящие под регулярное выражение. А потом `head -1` просто берёт первое из них.

Comment: @AlexeyTen, аааааа, спасибо большое!!!

Answer (score 3):

```
# seq генерирует входной алфавит - строчки с числами от 0 до 9
# shuf перемешивает строчки поданные на вход
# tr убирает переносы строк
# получается строка содержащая десятизначное число без повторений цифр
num="$(seq 0 9 | shuf - | tr -d "\n")"
# отрезаем потенциальный 0 в начале
num="${num#"0"}"
# берем первые четыре цифры
num="${num:0:4}"
```

Comment: Спасибо! Но тот вариант меня более чем устроил)))